# No Australian mirror on download page

Tags: mirror

I'm from Australia so obviously i would want the Aussie mirror. But when i go onto the downloads page there are only the US, German and both Netherlands mirrors. Please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about using ["Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games"](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As a sidebar, mirrors are much less important today, than they were years ago, when international long distance calls were expensive, and modem speeds were slow, than they are today, when the internet is more built out, and more economical.

Answer (score 3):

You can download Blender from any mirror you want. Australians can download from US, US can download from Netherlands, etc. If there's no Aussie mirror, just pick a different one.